# npm install is so fragile on windows

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I have a project using grunt build. Here is my packages.json.

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "^0.4.4",
  "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.7.3",
  "grunt-coffeelint": "0.0.10",
  "grunt-concurrent": "^0.5.0",
  "grunt-connect-proxy": "^0.1.10",
  "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
  "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
  "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
  "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
  "grunt-contrib-csslint": "^0.2.0",
  "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
  "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
  "grunt-contrib-less": "^0.11.0",
  "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.4",
  "grunt-contrib-stylus": "^0.15.1",
  "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
  "grunt-modernizr": "^0.5.2",
  "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
  "jshint-stylish": "^0.2.0",
  "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.4.0",
  "rjs-build-analysis": "0.0.3",
  "time-grunt": "^0.3.1"
},
...
```

I'm running npm `1.4.13` and node `v0.10.28`

There is always some random errors occur when I run clean `npm install`. And every time it is a different module. Then I have to run `npm cache clean` if the error is from the cache folder, or delete the `node_modules` if the error is in `node_modules` folder. Then I have to retry several times to bypass the error. I tried windows 8, windows 7, and windows server 2008. Here is one of the error logs.

```
C:\src>npm install
npm ERR! unpack Could not read data for sigmund@1.0.0
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod 'C:\src\node_modules\l
oad-grunt-tasks\node_modules\multimatch\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\lru-
cache\CONTRIBUTORS'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\src\\packages\\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\\no
dejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\src\\packages\\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\\n
odejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\src
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.13
npm ERR! path C:\src\node_modules\load-grunt-tasks\n
ode_modules\multimatch\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\lru-cache\CONTRIBUTOR
S
npm ERR! fstream_path C:\src\node_modules\load-grunt
-tasks\node_modules\multimatch\node_modules\minimatch\node_modules\lru-cache\CON
TRIBUTORS
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\no
dejs\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\sigmund\1.0.0\package\pack
age.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\src\\packages\\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\\no
dejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\src\\packages\\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\\n
odejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\src
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.13
npm ERR! file C:\Users\tim\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\sigmund\1.0.0\package\packa
ge.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\src\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

And sometimes it just failed to fetch modules from registry. For example:

```
npm WARN package.json rjs-build-analysis@0.0.3 No repository field.
npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: lodash
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate
.Node.0.10.28\nodejs\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:133:18)
npm ERR!     at cb (C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\nodej
s\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:32:9)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate
.Node.0.10.28\nodejs\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:107:16)
npm ERR!     at cb (C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\nodej
s\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:132:9)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate
.Node.0.10.28\nodejs\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:286:12)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate.Nod
e.0.10.28\nodejs\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:212:65)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate
.Node.0.10.28\nodejs\node_modules\request\request.js:123:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (C:\src\packages\Ncapsulate.N
ode.0.10.28\nodejs\node_modules\request\request.js:893:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\src\\packages\\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\\no
dejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\src\\packages\\Ncapsulate.Node.0.10.28\\n
odejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\src\npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.13
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\src\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I thought the remote npm registry was not stable, so I setup a local npm registry mirror. But the error still occurs. I don't know why npm is so unstable on windows.

Answer (score 1):

> npm ERR! registry error parsing json

The package.json file for the module in question is missing or has a syntax error

> npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: lodash

The module in question is not in the registry

> npm ERR! cwd C:\src

The path in question does not exist

> npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod 'C:\src\node_modules\l

No permissions to modify the path in question

Verify the installation process:

- Did you install as an admin, then run npm as a regular user?
- Did you install nodeJS into a protected directory?
- Did you set your PATH correctly?

**References**

- [Troubleshooting NPM](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: package.json is not completely downloaded so the syntax is wrong.
Windows doesn't have permission issue. And retry sometimes works.
The PATH is set and after several trial, the installation is succeed.